# Adobe Analytics Schema for Purchases

Tags: adobe-analytics

I am interested in finding out what the data looks like for an export from Adobe Analytics that contains purchase events. Essentially, I'd like to know what the columns are that would be available for a purchases export.

Thank you in advance for any insights.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're looking for. Are you looking for purchase info in relation to a data feed or DW request?

Comment: Maybe this is where my lack of knowledge about Adobe Analytics comes into play. I just want to know what data will look like for purchase events if I were able to export it either by DW or a data feed.

Comment: There is no default/out-of-the-box/generic/base/whatever report for this. When you send purchase event and associated data to Adobe Analytics, metrics and dimensions (namely product category and sku), as well as metrics (namely units and revenue). You can also send purchase related data to custom variables (props, eVars or other metrics for calculated metrics or whatever). All of these are essentially building blocks for reports, and Adobe offers many ways to present this stuff, as well as drill down, slice and dice, etc. So there isn't really a good way to answer what you are asking.

Comment: You are basically asking someone with a handful of legos "what can you build with this?"  So, if you want a more solid answer from someone, it would be better if you explain what your needs are. What format you are looking to get data in. Which data points, etc. and someone may be able to answer you on whether Adobe Analytics can do that and best method(s)

Comment: p.s. - I see you asked a similar question for Google Analytics. Well my response to that is basically the same as here, except that in general, Adobe Analytics has a lot more options for presentation/exportation than Google Analytics.

Comment: If it somehow helps, here is a screenshot of the Adobe Analytics Data Warehouse interface: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6uGb.png You specify the date range, segments, breakdowns (dimensions), metrics. Most people have it exported as a CSV file and on the bottom right of the screenshot is a preview of the structure. As mentioned in previous comments, it really depends on what dimension(s)/metrics(s) you specify.  You can also schedule it to send it regularly (e.g. send it every night for previous day), have it emailed or ftp'd to you, etc.